# Why do I need a finalizer if my class implements IDisposable?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-3.0

What about below disposable pattern?

```
using System;
public class MyClass : IDisposable 
{     
    public void Dispose() 
        // Implement IDisposable     
    {
        //just do the cleanup
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    } 

}
```

### Update

I meant to say, if there are no un-managed resources do I need finalizer? Isn't the above disposable pattern is good enough? Yes, even though users/developers doesn't invoke dispose, doesn't GC invoke dispose by default?

And what about the order in which GC invokes dispose and finalizers?

Please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10854708/standard-dispose-pattern-why-do-we-need-disposing-parameter-in-the-virtual-me) for more details.

In other words, when we have finalizer, why do we call `Dispose` with false as parameter?

---

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163392.aspx#S2, looks like its always advisable to release unmanaged resources from finalizer and not the managed references.

It's always recommended to release unmanaged resources from Dispose method. I still didn't get the total gist when reading the article.

But if there are no unmanaged resources, the below pattern should work.

---

According to msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163392.aspx#S2, msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs2xkftw.aspx it's recommended to release native resources in finalizer and all of them with dispose(). If dispose() is called explicitly, it can suppress finalizer i.e. if there no native resources, we don't need finalizer.

```
using System;
public class MyClass : IDisposable 
{ 
    private bool disposed = false;  
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool suppressFinalize) 
    {    
        if (!disposed)
        {
            //Just do the cleanup
            //and release resources
            disposed = true; 
        }
        if (!suppressFinalize)
        {
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this); 
        }
    }
    public void Dispose() 
        // Implement IDisposable     
    {
        Dispose(true);           
    } 
    ~MyClass() // the finalizer
    {     
        Dispose(false);    
    }
}
```

Comment: Implementing `IDisposable` does not in itself guarantees that `Dispose()` will be called.

Comment: Needing to add a finaliser is *really really rare*. Without more context as to why you think you need one, how can we possibly answer?

Comment: GUys, READ - you do not "need a finalizer" as in adding it. You tell the GC to NOT (!) finalize this object, AS IT ALREADY IS. SImple like that. Means the object does not go into finalization which means gc "run" isntead of 2 for releasing the memory.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, isnt GC calls Dispose when its collecting memory? say if i dont have un-managed resources, do i really need finalizer? if i dont have finalizer, will there be a default finalzier? do i need to suppress the call to finalizer?

Comment: @Dreamer No, GC does not call `Dispose`. In fact, it does differenciate between `IDisposable` objects and all other objects. If you do not have *direct* references to non-managed resources, you do not need a finalizer, and you do not need to suppress it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [standard dispose pattern? why do we need "disposing" parameter in the virtual method and isnt the fianlizer get called after dipose always?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10854708/standard-dispose-pattern-why-do-we-need-disposing-parameter-in-the-virtual-me)

Comment: This question seems to be exactly the last part of your previous one.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, do you mean to say it GC doesnt differentiate between Idisposable obejcts and other objects. Make sense. But still its recommended to call dispose with false from finalizer and recommended to release managed resources only from Dispose method directly. a bit confusing. still reading? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163392.aspx#S2

Comment: @Dreamer `Dispose` with a boolean parameter is not part of the `IDisposable` interface. It is for use by your own code, and the recommendation is to help you avoid code duplication. You can provide an implementation of `Dispose` and a finalizer that are completely independent of each other, but then you'd introduce code duplication, which is definitely not a good idea.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, can you please confirm - do you mean to say, GC doesnt differentiate between Idisposable obejcts and other objects or GC does differentiate between them? Btw, when i meant calling dispose(false), i am referring to the design patter/prototype. according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163392.aspx#S2, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs2xkftw.aspx its recommended to release native resources in finalizer and all of them with dispose(). if dispose() is called explicitely, it can suppress finalizer.i.e; if there no native reosurces, we dont need fianlizer.

Comment: @Dreamer GC does *not* differentiate between `IDisposable` obejcts and other objects. I know the pattern from your link - I needed to implement it once.

Answer (score 14):

Because you might have *direct* references to unmanaged resources (e.g. Windows handles) and you want to release them even if no-one calls `Dispose`.

This is very rare though - usually you only *really* have indirect references to unmanaged resources, via other managed types which will have finalizers if they need them.

Comment: This, to me, is "God's word" on the subject: http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/blog/PermaLink.aspx?guid=88e62cdf-5919-4ac7-bc33-20c06ae539ae

Comment: @LukePuplett: Yes, I'm aware of that article - but that's handling a *very general* case. This is one reason why sealed classes are useful: most of the pattern becomes unnecessary, as you don't need to worry about the possibility that a derived class may need its own disposal (and potentially a finalizer).

Answer (score 4):

Finalization + `IDisposable` in .Net is really two distinct problems which are attempted to be solved with the single disposable pattern.

- Managed resource cleanup
- Unmanaged resource cleanup

Unmanaged resources are items which aren't in the control of the CLR and garbage collector.  Items like file handles, memory returned from PInvoke, etc ...  If these resources aren't explicitly freed by user code they will leak and be around for the remainder of the process lifetime.  It's critical that they are freed.

This is where the finalizer comes in.  It will run on an object just before it is collected by the CLR.  This doesn't require the consumer follow the disposable pattern and hence is a good fallback for ensuring unmanaged resources are freed to prevent a leak.

If your code doesn't contain any directly held unmanaged resources then there is no reason to have a finalizer.  It is the responsibility of the code which holds the unmanaged resource to have the finalizer.