# garbage collection after a local method in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I'm a beginner in C#, just a question on garbage collection in C#. Let's say we have the following code:

```
...
public void Test()
{
   ...
   MyClass a = new Myclass()
}
```

so when will a be garbage collected by CLR? I mean immediately garbage collected after Test() method gets executed? or when the program finishes?

Comment: When the garbage collector feels the need, not a moment sooner

Comment: The whole point of working in a managed language with a GC is to be able to *pretend* that you're working with an infinite address space and not *worry* about when/how actual memory/address space is used and freed.

Answer (score 6):

Running this code will not let you control or know when the garbage collection will run, there are a number of conditions that will trigger the garbage collection:

> **Conditions for a garbage collection**
>
> - The system has low physical memory. This is detected by either the low
>   memory notification from the OS or low memory indicated by the host.
> - The memory that is used by allocated objects on the managed heap
>   surpasses an acceptable threshold. This threshold is continuously
>   adjusted as the process runs.
> - The GC.Collect method is called. In almost all cases, you do not have
>   to call this method, because the garbage collector runs continuously.
>   This method is primarily used for unique situations and testing.

More information: [Conditions for a garbage collection / learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/fundamentals#conditions_for_a_garbage_collection)

Comment: Very nice answer!

Answer (score 1):

Answer from : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1095402/Garbage-Collection-and-Csharp

## When GC Gets Triggered?

There are no specific timings for GC to get triggered, GC automatically starts operation on the following conditions:

- When virtual memory is running out of space.
- When allocated memory is suppressed acceptable threshold (when GC found if the survival rate (living objects) is high, then it increases the threshold allocation).
- When we call GC.Collect() method explicitly, as GC runs continuously, we actually do not need to call this method.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike in other languages, c# manages itself to clean up most resources for you. As you can read in other answers, resources are freed, when the GC detect's that they are not needed anymore and he has the time to do it. But if you really need to trigger this manually, you can use the `GC.Collect()` [Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.gc.collect?view=netframework-4.7.2).

If you are interested in freeing unmanaged resources (files, connections, [unmanaged code](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/managed-code-vs-unmanaged-code-in-chash), basically everything that is not controlled by the CLR) you should have a look into the dispose-pattern. Usually you would Implement the `IDisposable` interface. But there are really many handsome approaches to this, to also free unmanaged resources, even if `Dispose()` doesn't get called by the code. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10854708/standard-dispose-pattern-why-do-we-need-disposing-parameter-in-the-virtual-me).